# why am I getting multiple rows in MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, count, floor

I am trying to retrive a random row from a table (user), by using the Primary Key _id and the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user 
WHERE  _id IN (SELECT Floor(1 + ( Rand() * ( Count(_id) - 1 ) )) 
               FROM   user);
```

No rows have been deleted from the table but I (inconsistently) get multiple rows returned...

I find this amazing, as any result from the subquery should surely return one integer, which against a primary key.....should always only be 1 record!

I want to use one query, I will probably make it a prepared statement, and I am not using the LIMIT clause because I cannot use @variables to pick the random row.

My MySQL welcome statement tells me my version is as follows:
Server version: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Comment: do you have multiple `_id` of the same value? do a `SELECT _ID1, count(_id1) from user group by _id1 having count(_id1) > 1` if that returns row then that is your issue

Comment: Try running this part of your query (select FLOOR(1+(RAND()*(COUNT(_id)-1))) from user) or try replacing `IN` with `=`, if it gives you error you can know where is ther problem

Comment: @MattBusche I managed to reproduce this even for unique `_id` values. Please see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fda3/7; you'll get 0, 1 or 2 results.

Comment: @PawanNogariya it seems to behave the same with `=` instead of `IN`: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fda3/6

Comment: @PawanNogariya try it several times :)

Comment: I have posted my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;` in your query instead of `where _id IN (select FLOOR(1+(RAND()*(COUNT(_id)-1))) from user);`

You get multiple rows cause (select FLOOR(1+(RAND()*(COUNT(_id)-1))) from user) will return you a different value for ever record in 'user' table. That is because of the RAND bit.

Run `select FLOOR(1+(RAND()*(COUNT(_id)-1))) from user` on its own and you will see.

Comment: this is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: this is a good solution, but the question is not "How do I..."; it's "Why do I get multiple results?"

Comment: AH yes. Silly me. Once per row, Thank You!

Comment: And here is the link to the documentation where you can find all this information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Answer (score 1):

The random part gets evaluated once per row so sometimes you get many rows, sometimes you don't get any. To do it easy and fast use and equi-join and limit

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    user 
WHERE 
    _id > (
        SELECT 
            FLOOR(1+(RAND()*(max(_id)-min(_id)))) 
        FROM 
            user
    ) LIMIT 1
;
```

Comment: I don't think it's evaluated once per row; it uses `count`, therefore it's an aggregate which will always yield one value. You can try executing the subquery (`select FLOOR(1+(RAND()*(COUNT(_id)-1))) from user`) multiple times to confirm this.

Comment: +1 I take that back; I think this could be the explanation for the weird result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from user join (select FLOOR(1+(RAND()*(COUNT(_id)-1))) as _id from user) as Temp
on user._id=Temp._id
```

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fda3/11